# Very poor results Word2Vec

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I think there is something I am missing because I am trying to do a Word2Vec, but the results are so bad I think something is wrong.
Here is my code:

```
# 1.65 million documents of 15-20 words each
documents = [['example','of','input'],
             ['second','sentence','of','input'],
             ['this','is','a','list','of','lists']]

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(documents, size=100, workers=-1, window=3)
model.train(documents, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=30)
```

First, the training runs very fast (I expected long time for training with 30 epochs?)
And then when I look for most similar words the results seems completely random, nothing related.

Is there something I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: first you should show your results in question (not in comment). We can't run it and we can't read in your mind - so you have to put all details in questions. Or you could create minimal working code with all needed elements to run it  - ie. `import` - and then we could run it and see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to call `.train()` if you supplied the training-texts to the object initialization. When you provide the corpus, it will run the necessary steps itself. So, you already have a working model, trained on `documents`, using the default 5 epochs, after running:

```py
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(documents, size=100, workers=-1, window=3)
```

Running an extra 30 epochs after already doing initializer-training probably isn't a good idea. If you need to do the `build_vocab()`/`train()` steps yourself for some reason, don't specify the corpus at object initialization. On the other hand, if you just want the standard corpus treatment, just specify the corpus and your preferred `epochs`/etc all up-front.

Second, it'd be clearer what's happening – if anything – if you enable logging at the INFO level before running anything:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

If log output shows steps are completing instantly even on what should be large amounts of data, or reporting nonsense counts of words discovered/processed that don't match expectations, then you may have a better hint as to what isn't working as expected.

Finally, your symptom (training instant * bad results) is exactly what would be expected from the tiny 3-text, 13-word corpus you're showing. While you report that your real data may be "1.65 million documents of 15-20 words each", since the code for feeding that data to the model isn't shown, it's quite possible that the problem is in that unshown step, such that the real data *isn't* being given to the model, or not given in the right format.

So, if you still have a perplexing problem after enabling logging, expand your question with more info about how the real data is handled (or ask a followup with those extra details.)

Comment: thanks for this, I removed the train() function and inserted the logging function. I can see where the problem is but I dont know why. It processes the vocab and ends with a big vocabulary (~40k vocab) but when it start the epoch training it says "training with 0 words (0 effective words)" for all five epochs.. any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/319 I think it is related to that. I am goin to take a look at it.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the `documents` sequence you're passing in your real work. Without seeing the code you're using, it's hard to guess what's going wrong. Maybe you're using a single-pass `iterator` objct, instead of a true sequence that can be iterated over many times (a true `Iterable`)? If your data fits in RAM, turning a iterator into a `list` will make it re-iterable. If too large, writing code which does the right thing, streaming the data anew every ime an iteration is started, is necessary. (Usually this only requires a few lines of code.)